# Read CSV file using a pattern in AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a logic to read a file from S3. But am looking for a logic to read the file dynamically using a pattern. I wanted to check a pattern ***_2023.csv** despite **data_2023.csv** as the file name changes often

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={
        "quoteChar": '"',
        "withHeader": True,
        "separator": ",",
        "optimizePerformance": False,
    },
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "s3://s1bucket/data_2023.csv"
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="df",
).toDF()
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any other file in the folder, you can just use *

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={
        "quoteChar": '"',
        "withHeader": True,
        "separator": ",",
        "optimizePerformance": False,
    },
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "s3://s1bucket/*"
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="df",
).toDF()
```

or just simply use spark context and read

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load('s3://s1bucket/*')
```

Comment: I have tried already, "s3://s1bucket/*.csv", did not work

Comment: can you share the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

Glue Context (glueContext) does not support pattern matching right now.
But spark session does.

Using below solved the issue,

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

df_userlisting = spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load("s3://s1bucket/*.csv")
```